# Range minimum Query

Tags: c++, segment-tree, rmq

This is rmq using segment tree.
But i am not getting correct output can anybody tell me where i am wrong.
`

```
#include<iostream>
 #include<cmath>
 #define inf 1e9
using namespace std;
int get_mid(int a,int b){
    return a+(b-a)/2;
}
int min(int a,int b){
    int temp=(a<b)?a:b;
    return temp;
}
int get_min_util(int str[],int beg,int end,int l,int r,int i){
    if(l<=beg && r>=end)
    return str[i];
    if(l>end || r<beg){
        return 0; ////////c1
      }
    int mid=get_mid(beg,end);
    return (get_min_util(str,beg,mid,l,r,2*i+1),get_min_util(str,mid+1,end,l,r,2*i+2));
}
int get_min(int str[],int len,int l,int r){
    if(l<0 || r>len-1 || l>r){
        return 0;
    }
    else
    return get_min_util(str,0,len-1,l,r,0);
}
int build_rmq_arr_util(int str[],int beg,int end,int big_arr[],int i){
    if(beg==end){
        big_arr[i]=str[beg];
        return big_arr[i];
    }
    int mid=get_mid(beg,end);
    big_arr[i]=min(build_rmq_arr_util(str,beg,mid,big_arr,2*i+1),build_rmq_arr_util(str,mid+1,end,big_arr,2*i+2));
    return big_arr[i];
}
int*bulid_rmq_arr(int str[],int len){
    int temp=ceil(log2(len));
    temp=2*pow(2,temp)-1;
    int *big_arr=new int[temp];
    build_rmq_arr_util(str,0,len-1,big_arr,0);
    return big_arr;
}
void pop(int arr[],int size){
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
int main(){
    int str[]={1,2,3,4,5,6};
    int len=sizeof(str)/sizeof(int);
    int *rmq_arr;
    rmq_arr=bulid_rmq_arr(str,len);
    //pop(rmq_arr,3*len);
    cout<<get_min(rmq_arr,len,1,2);
}
```

`
output of this code:
0
expected output in range 1-2 is 2
function get_min_util return 0 from if condition where comment ////////c1 is written

Comment: With small input and expected output, using debugger could help.

Answer (score 0):

problem is in get_min_util().It should return infinity when not in range.Also you have to return minimum of left and right child.

```
int get_min_util(int str[],int beg,int end,int l,int r,int i){
if(l<=beg && r>=end)
return str[i];
if(l>end || r<beg){
    return inf; ////////c1
  }
int mid=get_mid(beg,end);
return min(get_min_util(str,beg,mid,l,r,2*i+1),get_min_util(str,mid+1,end,l,r,2*i+2));
}
```